# Efficient sums of n-length combinations of array

Tags: python, performance, combinations

Given the following input:

- An integer `n`, e.g., `36`.
- An list/array `mylist` of length `m`, e.g., `[0.0, 24.0, 48.0, 72.0, 96.0, 120.0]`. Although the values in this example are evenly spaced and integer-valued floats, they are not necessarily evenly spaced and they are in general non-negative real numbers.

I am trying to do the following computational steps:

1. Generate a list of `n`-length combinations (with replacement) of `mylist`, e.g. for `n == 3`:

   ```
   [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
   [0.0, 0.0, 24.0]
   ...
   [120.0, 120.0, 96.0]
   [120.0, 120.0, 120.0]
   ```
2. Sum the elements of each combination in the above list, e.g. for `n == 3`:

   ```
   0
   24.0
   ...
   336.0
   360.0
   ```
3. Removing duplicates from the above list of sums, e.g., reducing the list length from 56 to 16 for `n == 3` or from 749,398 to 181 for `n == 36`.

I have implemented this in Python in two ways: using `list`s and using `pandas.DataFrame`s. For values of `n` as high as 36+, the above steps take too long for my application (1+ seconds) due to the exponential nature of combinations. Although performing steps 2 and 3 on a `DataFrame` brings speed improvements, creating the `DataFrame` from the list of combinations makes the overall process slower again.

Implementation using `list`s:

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

n = 36
mylist = [0.0, 24.0, 48.0, 72.0, 96.0, 120.0]

combinations = list(combinations_with_replacement(mylist, n))  # Step 1.
combination_sums = list(map(sum, combinations))                # Step 2.
unique_combination_sums = list(set(combination_sums))          # Step 3.
```

Implementation using `DataFrame`s:

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

import pandas as pd

n = 36
mylist = [0.0, 24.0, 48.0, 72.0, 96.0, 120.0]

combinations_df = pd.DataFrame(list(combinations_with_replacement(mylist, n)))  # Step 1.
combination_sums_df = combinations_df.sum(axis=1)                               # Step 2.
unique_combination_sums_df = combination_sums_df.drop_duplicates()              # Step 3.
```

Note: Using `numpy.ndarray`s is computationally faster than using `DataFrame`s but slower than using `list`s.

Is there a more efficient algorithm, library, or other technique to make the above process faster? Perhaps something that takes advantage of the tree-like nature of combinations?

Comment: Your example `mylist` is equivalent to `[p*i for i in range(m+1)]` with p=24.0, m=5. Will it always be of that form (in which case the number of distinct sums is `m*n + 1` and the sums themselves are `[p*j for j in range(m*n + 1)]`), or can it contain arbitrary values?

Comment: What are your real n and m? Are your numbers always integer floats? What's their range?

Comment: @slothrop `mylist` contains monotonically increasing non-negative real numbers that are not necessarily evenly spaced or integers.

Comment: @KellyBundy My real n and m for which I'm currently trying to increase the computational efficiency are n = 36 and m = 6, as in my example Python implementations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `myList` can be anything (i.e. we can't rely on it having equally spaced values like in the example) you could try something like this. The idea is to build up the sums of length-1 combinations, then all the sums of length-2 combinations, etc, uniquifying at each step rather than only at the end.

```
mylist = [0.0, 24.0, 48.0, 72.0, 96.0, 120.0]
n = 36

sums = {0}
for i in range(n):
  # All the sums from a combination of (i+1) terms:
  sums = {s + p for s in sums for p in mylist}

print(len(sums))
```

Generates 181 sums for your example, as expected.

I haven't tested speed in much detail, but from a quick run on replit, using your `mylist`, n can go to about 550 without the runtime exceeding 1 second. That input is probably a bit flattering though, since the number of distinct sums is smaller for a list of equally spaced values than for an arbitrary input list.

Comment: Excellent and very efficient solution, thank you! And you're right that `mylist` can be "anything".

Answer (score 2):

For any arbitrary input list recursive approach is more efficient.
It avoids permutations that will give the same result (like [0, 1, 2], [2, 1, 0])

```
def dankal(input_list, n):
    unique_sums = set()
    for i in range(n + 1):
        if len(input_list) == 1:
            unique_sums.add(input_list[0] * n)
        else:
            current_item_sum = i * input_list[0]
            downstream_sums = dankal(input_list[1:], n - i)
            for item in downstream_sums:
                unique_sums.add(item + current_item_sum)
    return unique_sums
```

Compared to slothrop version:

- it is much slower for equally spaced input
- it is much faster for random input
  [image]

Probably, using lists (or even better, numpy arrays) instead of sets would make this algorithm faster

Comment: What do all those numbers in your screenshot mean?

Comment: Why the strange assertion instead of `assert res1 == res2`?

Comment: You're not changing `input_list` in the loop, so better move some stuff out of the loop. Both for efficiency and for clarity

Comment: If you wrap your recursive function inside some other function, you could replace its list parameter with an index parameter. Adding 1 is cheaper than slicing. And the parameters would be two ints, so you could decorate with `lru_cache` or `cache`.

Comment: @KellyBundy 1) %of function time, number of hits, time in microseconds (I guess) 2) didn't know it is ok to compare this way. 3) good idea, 4) I'll leave it as a task for OP :)